# How to Know if user has downloaded a file or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cron

I have a PHP file which have a button with the help of which I want to download a file, I want to try this using AJAX call to PHP, (Because, I feel it is more secure), Currently, I have the following code...

```
<a onclick="download_file (<?= $row["id"]?>)">Download</a>
```

And then the function of download_file looks like this:

```
function download_file (fileid)
{
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'download.php',
    data: {id: fileid},
    success: function(data)
    {
     window.location = 'download.php?link='+data;
    }
  });
}
```

Now what this does is that it first calls `download.php` with a `POST` request (so as to keep the location a bit more secure) with `fileid` in order for the script to fetch the location of the file from from the database and return it back to the AJAX script as `data` variable.

Now what next is that in the success function, `download.php` is again called but this time with a `GET` request, and then the file is searched, renamed (as in server, they have random filenames) and then downloaded... The PHP code for that is:

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file."");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: binary/octet-stream"); 
readfile ($link);
```

Now, everything works perfectly, my concern is about security, I want to make the files more secure, I want something like a random and unique download link is generated and after the download have been completed, the link is disposed off, but the file remains intact... I have thought of a way to create a temp file with another address and use cron job to delete the temp file, but that gives a window of some time as for that particular amount of time interval of cron jobs, the download link will be static, which is not good for the site... I want that a single link should be valid for a single download only, (But the link should be there for the whole of download, i.e. RESUME SHOULD BE SUPPORTED).

Or if possible, can I use an authentication for that too, like if the user is logged in, download link will be active but as soon as the user logs out of the app and opens the download link, then it should prompt the user to either login or show a 404 Error...

And I also want suggestion of how to improve the security of the same by any other method...

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a proxy which will be called before your download.php is called. Basically your proxy will do the following things:

1. Authenticate the user based on your session.
2. Generate a UNIQUE download link. For this, you have to maintain some sort of mapping between your user and the newly generated link.
3. Pass this newly generated link which will passed as a parameter to your `success` callback function.
4. AJAX call to the download.php link which will start downloading the file. You should again reauthenticate the use on download.php with the mapping you created between the user and the download link in the database or somewhere else. I would prefer using database as you would have to maintain some download history.
5. After your download is finished, mark this mapping as Inactive into your DB and redirect to some sort of 404 page or something, if the user again tries to hit this URL.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: But how would I know that the user has completed downloading.?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to figure that out, as the download process is entirely handled on the client side/browser. The closest you can do is to assume that the user has downloaded the file if he/she has started the downloading process.

Comment: But then I have files as large as 10 MB, and what if the Internet speed of user is really bad, Like in Kb/s, well In that case, the download will fail as the link will be deleted whereas the download didn't complete... So, no transfer at all...

Comment: Yes, that's true. But that's an issue on the client side and there's no way of figuring that out. Implement some sort of Retry mechanism which will generate a new unique link which the user can use if his download fails.

Comment: I was wandering if I can tell browser to execute a script after download have been completed, so that will make an AJAX call to another script which will flush the download link...

Comment: Telling the browser to raise an event if the download is finished would be outside the scope of your application. So, in short, you can't really do it.